# UE4 c++ and blueprint share input

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Im trying to make a game and used a bit of c++ for a grabber and open door function where I bind in both of them the e key called Interaction to theyr respective usage, now im trying to make a dialog box and had to use some blueprint and linked the e button, the same as before to the show ui function but whenever I bind it and start the game my other two c++ bind don't won't work and when the dialog one is deactivated my two c++ one will work. So yeah I was wondering how could I use blueprint and c++ at the same time on the same keybind. I tried for the moment to create a new input on the same key and the [roblem persist and I cannot find any usefull information on the net.

Answer (score 2):

In nutshell, **APlayerController::PushInputComponent(UInputComponent InputComponent)**, this method will help register your Actor, Widget or anything you want to bind input event.
So it is OK that bind same key to multiple Actors' behavior, but you need concern that this KEY will be consumed in default, in your case, after construction of UInputComponent, while bind action, you may set InputComponent->BindAction(…).bConsumeInput = false.
This flag indicates that if delegate calling will consume this key, so lower priority input component is still eligible to trigger.

Comment: This helped me big time. Thank you